# Should I take (Pen test) approval from AWS for Fuzz testing my Application API's hosted on AWS?

Tags: penetration-test, aws, fuzzing

I wanted to Fuzz Tests my API's on my own stack which are hosted on AWS environment (Have used lambdas and API gateway)

There are mostly GET APIs and only one PUT API.My requirement is to Fuzz Test the API headers and the body. For this I'm planning to use file fuzzing techniques with certain payloads.

Do I need to take a Pen testing approval from AWS for my Fuzz Testing?

Quick response would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is a question to ask AWS support. The available documentation (using a quick search) says "yes"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will still need to raise a ticket with AWS. You can find their policy here: 
https://aws.amazon.com/security/penetration-testing/

They have no specific guidelines on what penetration testing consists of, but if you are using CloudFront or ELB, they may detect abnormal behavior. Therefore it's safer to register and to prevent an abuse notice.

Also note that even when hosting your own application on EC2 you cannot test on  m1.small, t1.micro or t2.nano.